# Is it possible to get facebook feed from a public group that I belong to but do not own?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried many way but FB throw me an error `user permission` or `OAuthException`.
Since graph API v2.4 FB has removed user_group permission so we can't get news feed through this link

`http://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR GROUP ID}/feed?access_token={ACCESS TOKEN}`

anyone know how to get news feed in public group? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

No.

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/feed#read explains, you need an access token from a group admin, that includes `user_managed_groups` permission.